Python: Is there a way of stopping an inifinite loop running on a python Class method?
I am running a loop on a python Class method that depends on a boolean variable. When I try to change the value of the variable from outside, it seems like it is stucked in the loop and I cannot change nor run the next lines.
import time
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.boolean = True
    
    def test1(self):
        while self.boolean:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(self.counter)
            self.counter += 1


class Test2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = Test()
        self.test.test1()
        
    def stop_test(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Now I change the boolean value")
        self.test.boolean = False

test = Test2()
print("What is going on?")
test.stop_test()

This code sums up my problem.
I expected the loop to end, but instead the loop keeps running and the code is only printing the value of self.counter

The only thread is busy with executing the loop and can't do anything else. You need a second thread. See module threading in the standard library.

That code is synchronous which means that it needs to finish execution of self.test.test1() and then it will proceed on next command. In your example, it will start the loop and it won't exit function until loop finishes. In that time that loop is looping, no other code can be executed (at least not in way you are trying to do). If you want to have two commands working at the same time, check out threading.

You cannot change the value outside because you never reach outside. Run it in a console, and press Control-C, so you see where your code is. As you see, you will be on the Test2.__init__, which call test1. PS: learn to use better variable names, also for tests and examples: it helps you instead of remembering what is test (which it is not Test: different classes), test1, test2 -- Do not worry if you need to spend some minutes to thingk about it.

Yes in a single thread program like that you have to put a condition for escaping the loop in the loop itself.

You can acheive by threading, something like:
import time
import threading

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.boolean = True
    
    def test1(self):
        while self.boolean:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(self.counter)
            self.counter += 1

class Test2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = Test()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.test.test1)  # Run test1 in a separate thread
        self.thread.start()  # Start the thread
        
    def stop_test(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Now I change the boolean value")
        self.test.boolean = False

test = Test2()
print("What is going on?")
test.stop_test()


Have a look at this modified example:
please note that now your class Test is based on the Thear class, wich implements the Thread.run() method. The run() method is called by the Thread class when start() is called.
import time
from threading import Thread


class Test(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.counter = 0
        self.boolean = True

    def run(self):
        while self.boolean:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(self.counter)
            self.counter += 1


class Test2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = Test()
        self.test.start()

    def stop_test(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Now I change the boolean value")
        self.test.boolean = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Test2()
    print("What is going on?")
    test.stop_test()


Your loop needs to be running asynchronously - e.g., in another thread.
Better practice (IMHO) is to use Events rather than simple boolean types because an Event offers additional functionality such as wait().
from threading import Thread, Event
from time import sleep

class Foo(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._event = Event()
    @property
    def event(self):
        return self._event
    def run(self): # this is called during Thread.start()
        # wait for the Event to be set
        self.event.wait()
        # for as long as the Event is set
        while self.event.is_set():
            print("Sleeping")
            sleep(1)
        # Event has been cleared
        print("Stopping")
    def stop(self):
        self.event.clear()
    def start(self):
        super().start()
        self.event.set()

class Bar():
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = Foo()
        self._foo.start()
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *_):
        self._foo.stop()
        self._foo.join()


with Bar():
    sleep(5)

Output:
Sleeping
Sleeping
Sleeping
Sleeping
Sleeping
Stopping

